# Cannot connect tot Cloud SQL with php

Tags: php, mysql, google-cloud-sql

I currently have a Cloud SQL database from Google and a web/PHP server from Namecheap. I am trying to use a PHP script from my Namecheap server to connect and insert data into a table in my Cloud SQL DB. My PHP script works for the database that my Namecheap account provides, but not when I make the credential and host changes for my new Cloud SQL connection. I know that I can make a connection from my IP and they are correct as I can connect to the Cloud SQL DB from MySQL Workbench.

Error:

```
[11-Oct-2017 19:28:12 America/New_York] PHP Warning:  mysqli_connect(): 
(HY000/2003): Can't connect to MySQL server on '35.199.10.53' (111 
&quot;Connection refused&quot;) in 
/home/dumamwny/public_html/php/googlemule.php on line 11
[11-Oct-2017 19:28:12 America/New_York] PHP Notice:  Trying to get property 
of non-object in /home/dumamwny/public_html/php/googlemule.php on line 26
[11-Oct-2017 19:28:12 America/New_York] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: 
Call to a member function query() on string in 
/home/dumamwny/public_html/php/php2.php:16
Stack trace:
#0 {main}
thrown in /home/dumamwny/public_html/php/php2.php on line 16
```

Any suggestions are welcome, below is my code.

googlemule.php

```
<?php
    function db_connect() {

        // Define connection as a static variable, to avoid connecting more than once 
    static $muleconnection;

        // Try and connect to the database, if a connection has not been established yet
    if(!isset($muleconnection)) {
             // Load configuration as an array. Use the actual location of your configuration file
        $config = parse_ini_file('/home/dumamwny/private/googlemule.ini'); 
        $muleconnection = mysqli_connect($config['servername'],$config['username'],$config['password'],$config['dbname']);
    }

        // If connection was not successful, handle the error
    if($muleconnection === false) {
            // Handle error - notify administrator, log to a file, show an error screen, etc.
        return mysqli_connect_error(); 
    }
    return $muleconnection;
    }

    // Connect to the database
    $muleconnection = db_connect();

    // Check connection
    if ($muleconnection->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $muleconnection->connect_error);
    }
    ?>
```

php2.php

```
<?php
require_once('googlemule.php');

$charName = $_POST['charName'];
$logType = $_POST['logType'];
$magicPrice = $_POST['magicPrice'];
$magicAmount = $_POST['magicAmount'];
$yewPrice = $_POST['yewPrice'];
$yewAmount = $_POST['yewAmount'];
$totalWealth = $_POST['totalWealth'];

$sql = "INSERT INTO dumaismule (char_name, log_type, magic_log_price, 
magic_log_amount, yew_log_price, yew_log_amount, total_wealth)
VALUES ($charName, $logType, $magicPrice, $magicAmount, $yewPrice, 
$yewAmount, $totalWealth)";


$query = $muleconnection->query($sql);
echo 'OK..';

?>
```

Comment: that isn't the only problem with your code, it's not just the connection issue.

Comment: What else would I need to do other than changing the credentials/host/dbname from my namecheap's db to my google cloud sql db?

Comment: Did you whitelist the IP of the namecheap host?

Comment: Yes I did, thank you

Comment: *"What else would I need to do other than changing"* - String literals require them to be quoted @RDumais Ref: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/string-literals.html